# How can I record sub-bass frequencies?

Tags: audio-recording

i live in a flat the people that live below play low frequency noise 24 hours a day. When environment protection put recorder's in it don't pick it up. I have been told to buy a camcorder but i've bought so many things that don't pick the noise up. I have high pitch buzzing throughout the day and around 2am i have the bass hitting the floor it comes up under my pillow making it impossible to sleep. Can you advise me on what mic or equipment i can buy that will work. I have had people to stay that hear it very clearly and can't wait to leave

Answer (score 2):

Find a local music gear store that rents professional recording equipment.

Tell them you want to rent their best kick drum condenser microphone and USB audio interface.

Plug the kick drum mic into the usb audio interface, and plug the interface into the computer. Then load audacity on your computer, and record the mic.

Good luck,
Sleep well ;)